# AutocompleteTextView (Suggestions incorrect)

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a customAdapter that extends from `AutoCompleteTextView`, I have a problem to show suggestions, I think is cause of "`performFiltering`" But I don't know well.

This is my code adapter :

What I'm doing wrong ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView  {
    Context context;
    public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
        context = context;
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    private boolean mIsKeyboardVisible;

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {

        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (getWindowVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            Log.d("InstantAutoComplete", "Window not visible, will not show drop down");
            return;
        }
        if (focused) {
            /*try {*/
                performFiltering(getText(), 0);
            /*}catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
        }
        mIsKeyboardVisible = focused;
    }



    /*@Override
    public View getRootView() {
        return super.getRootView();
    }*/

    /*@Override
    protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
        String filterText = "";
        super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
    }*/
```

**I put a Image :** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B5yD.png)

if I use "AutoCompleteTextView" works correctly, but if use "custom not works"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

Use a default ArrayAdapter. I get errors with custom adapter.